# Angular: return from service observable value

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component, where I call function from service:

```
// Component
constructor (myService: MyService) { } 

getData() {
  this.myService.getTableData()
}
```

```
// Service
getTableData() {
   task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
     finalize(() => {
       ref.getTableId().subscribe(id => id))
     })
   ).subscribe()
}
```

How can I receive this `id` which I receive inside `finalize` operator inside `getData()` method in my component? I would like to have something like:

```
getData() {
   this.myService.getTableData().then(id => console.log(id))
}
```

Comment: `then` means you have to return promise from the method, you need `subscribe()` to get the values from Observable

Comment: why you are using finalize in this case ? and what means `id => id` ?

Comment: It looks like you're looking for `concatMap` or `mergeMap` but it's very unclear what you want to do. What is the `finalize` block for anyway?

Comment: @martin I use `finalize` because firebase documentation says to use it for needed function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribes from the component instead of service. Also, you don't have to use `then` for observable. use only `subscribe` for that. `then` is use to handle the promises.

```
// Service
getTableData() {
   return task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
     finalize(() => ref.getTableId())
   )
}

getData() {
   this.myService.getTableData().subscribe(id => console.log(id))
}
```